# Combo Bar Line Chart with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

My line chart is not showing on my chart.js at all.  What piece of the puzzle am i missing here?

Also here is a fiddle that shows my code, you can see the bar graph displays as expected but the line chart does not.  https://jsfiddle.net/c50dfw3g/1/

I have never used this type of chart before so I am not certain how exactly to set it up.  Thanks in advance to all who assist.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var config = {
    type: 'bar',
  options: {
    legendCallback: function(chart) {
      var text = [];
      text.push('<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend">');
      var data = chart.data;
      var datasets = data.datasets;
      if (datasets.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < datasets.length; ++i) {
            text.push('<li>');
            if (datasets[i].type=='line') {
            text.push('<span class="'+datasets[i].type+'" style="background-color:' + datasets[i].backgroundColor + '"></span>');
          } else {
            text.push('<span class="'+datasets[i].type+'" style="background-color:' + datasets[i].backgroundColor + '"></span>');
          }
          text.push(datasets[i].label);
          text.push('</li>');
        }
      }
      text.push('</ul>');
      return text.join('');
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "category",
        id: "axis-bar",
      }, {
        type: "time",
        id: "axis-time",
        display: false,
      }, ],
    },
  },
  data: {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Dataset1",
      type: "line",
      backgroundColor: "#0000FF",
      borderColor: "#0000FF",
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: false,
      xAxisID: "axis-time",
      data: [12296,12381,9141,24203,21987,21801,65394,91892,57645,44637,22631,17502]
    },{
      label: "Dataset2",
      type: "bar",
      backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
      borderColor: "#ff0000",
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: true,
      xAxisID: "axis-bar",
      data: [299405,244029,247191,329711,273855,441914,426271,471912,374388,366864,326155,277442]
    }]
  },

};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
var legend = myChart.generateLegend();
document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = legend;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the same X-axis for both data sets:

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: "category",
    id: "axis-bar",
  }/* Commenting out the second axis, { 
    type: "time",
    id: "axis-time",
    display: true,
  }, */],
},
```

Now, we'll set the `line` dataset to use this X-axis:

```
datasets: [{
  label: "Dataset1",
  type: "line",
  backgroundColor: "#0000FF",
  borderColor: "#0000FF",
  borderWidth: 1,
  fill: false,
  xAxisID: "axis-bar",
  data: [12296,12381,9141,24203,21987,21801,65394,91892,57645,44637,22631,17502]
},
```

And here we go:

[image]

Comment: That remedies he fiddle, but when i paste into my site, I get this error in the console ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Object.acquireContext (Chart.min.js:13)
    at t.construct (Chart.min.js:11)
    at new t (Chart.min.js:12)
    at index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=635:1381```

Comment: i have this included in the page ```<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js""></script>```

Comment: It looks like it's executing `var legend = myChart.generateLegend();` before Chart.min.js is loaded from your CDN. Can you make your JS execute after page load?

Comment: i thought that was the culprit.  I completely removed that line from the bottom of my js and the issue still persists

Comment: I created a Glitch project with your code which works, please check it out: https://fantastic-lunar-torta.glitch.me/

Comment: Actually the line that is giving the error is ```text.push('</ul>');``` - the glitch you created doesn't have the line graph going across the bottom?

Comment: I switched it back to the new code with the line graph and added an HTML element with id `legend`, and it works with no errors: https://fantastic-lunar-torta.glitch.me/

Comment: it's got to be something with my local intance then, as you have pointed out and I have confirmed testing online works outside the realm of my local set-up.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the 'xAxisID' attributes.

You specify the x-axis id as: 'axis-bar' but then use a different id when specifying dataset 1 ('axis-time'), so it's not being plotted on the same graph.

Just use the same id in the datasets as you specify when defining the scale of the graph and you'll get both plots on the same chart and thus your desired result.

Comment: Doing this I get this error ``Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null     at Object.acquireContext (Chart.min.js:13)     at t.construct (Chart.min.js:11)     at new t (Chart.min.js:12)     at index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=635:1381``